# How to convert JSON array to OBJECT array javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, arrayobject

Kinda stuck here.

I am fetching data from database with php into this variable in javascript.

```
<?php
//connection to database
include("con.php");
//query
$query = "SELECT * FROM magacin_artikli";

$r = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$dataGrafDodArt = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
  $dataGrafDodArt[] = $row["art_naz"]. ":". $row["art_nabcena"];

}

//closing conn
$conn->close();

?>
```

```
var oData = <?php echo json_encode($dataGrafDodArt);?>;
```

Output is:

```js
var oData = ["asd:2","asd:3","asd:2","ddd:3"];
```

And I need this to be formated like object array like this("asd":2), something like this inside variable:

Example output:

```
var oData = {
  "2008": 10,
  "2009": 39.9,
  "2010": 17,
  "2011": 30.0,
  "2012": 5.3,
  "2013": 38.4,
  "2014": 15.7,
  "2015": 9.0
};
```

This is for animated graph which is taking parameters from Example output.

Any help would be good.

Tried a lot of things from array map to trimming the array and other stuff but none worked.

Comment: Where would the [years I'm assuming] come from? Are they in your array?
What does View Source say is being output?

Comment: The better way to get php data from server is making an AJAX request.

Comment: @amphetamachine years are from mysql database and they are loaded right into var oData without error.

Comment: Put the actual output. Not `"asd" or "ddd"`

Comment: @SebastianSimon I updated the php part in which I am getting the table.

Comment: *"Output is: ... Example output"*: I don't see any connection between the two. Can you explain how to get the second from the first?

Comment: @itachi its the actual otput. I just need that output to be formated to the Example output so it goes "asd:2" like this "asd": 2

Comment: `$dataGrafDodArt[] = $row["art_naz"]. ":". $row["art_nabcena"];` adds a string to a regular array. You probably mean `$dataGrafDodArt[$row["art_naz"]] = $row["art_nabcena"];`. Just read the [documentation](//www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Comment: Can you edit your question and make the two outputs consistent with eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the change at the PHP side. Instead of building an *indexed* array, create an *associative* array, and it will look in JavaScript just as you wanted it.

Change this:

```php
$dataGrafDodArt[] = $row["art_naz"]. ":". $row["art_nabcena"];
```

To:

```php
$dataGrafDodArt[$row["art_naz"]] = $row["art_nabcena"];
```